# Hibernate : Data stored in database without commiting

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, persistence

I'm using hibernate to add my objects into the database.
When I call `sessionCacti.save(Object object)` it stores the object to database while the object shouldn't not be stored because I didn't commit the changes and I use a non auto-commit mode.
Here is the file of the configuration of hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- pcac is the database name -->

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://uaeipvm1:3307/pcac?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            myadmin
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            dbaft
        </property>



        <!-- 1: READ UNCOMMITTED 2: READ COMMITTED 4: REPEATABLE READ 8: SERIALIZABLE -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>



        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="Host.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="HostGraph.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="HostTemplate.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="HostTemplateGraph.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Settings.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is my program :

```
public class SynchroCacti {
    public static Map<String,Host> hosts = new HashMap<String, Host>();
    private static SessionFactory factoryDerbi,factoryCacti;  
    private static Transaction tx=null;
    private static Session sessionDerbi,sessionCacti;
    public static List<Equipment> derbiEquipments;
    private static List<HostTemplate> hostTemplates;
    private static List<Settings> settings;
    private static int nbNewHosts = 0;
    private static int initialNbCactiHost,initialNbDerbiEqpts;

    public static void initializeData ()
    {
        try{
            factoryDerbi = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate_derbi.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            factoryCacti = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate_cacti.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            sessionDerbi = factoryDerbi.openSession();
            sessionCacti = factoryCacti.openSession();
            tx = sessionCacti.beginTransaction();
        }catch (Throwable ex) { 
            logErrorsInProgram.error("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
        }

        //Store tables of the database in these lists
        derbiEquipments = sessionDerbi.createCriteria(Equipment.class).list();
        List<Host> cactiHosts = sessionCacti.createCriteria(Host.class).list();
        hostTemplates = sessionCacti.createCriteria(HostTemplate.class).list();
        settings = sessionCacti.createCriteria(Settings.class).list();
        //Initialize the hash map of hosts
        Iterator<Host> it = cactiHosts.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Host actual = it.next();
            hosts.put(actual.getDescription(), actual);
        }
        //Initialize values of initialNbCactiHost and initialNbDerbiEqpts from sizes of lists
        initialNbCactiHost = hosts.size();
        initialNbDerbiEqpts = derbiEquipments.size();
    }



    public static void addHostToDatabase (Host host)
    {
        nbNewHosts++;
        try{
            sessionCacti.save(host); 
        }catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        }finally { //We don't close session 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HibernateException, SQLException, ParseException {

        initializeData();
        Host host = createHost(derbiEquipments.get(0));
        addHostToDatabase(host);
    }
}
```

I don't want to save data until I execute `tx.commit();`
Thanks.

Comment: How do you believe that you used a non auto-commit mode? Which config? Where?

Comment: Normally it is the default mode.
I also tried to add the property : 
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
But it didn't work

Comment: You aren't using MyISAM tables, right?

Comment: No, I'm not using them